# Formulate the experiment strategy

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, social-science

I performed an experiment in which I have three conditions, the baseline as the control compared to two other treatment conditions in a between-subject design, can I formulate this study as a 1x3 between-subject experiment?

Comment: Yes, so long as the population of interest is well-defined and the conditions are randomized.  Using a within-subject design may be cheaper but leads to many other considerations such as the dependency between a single subjects measurements for each condition and whether the order that the conditions are measured have a significant effect.

Comment: Thanks, but if I would like to correctly formulate this design how I can do it (1(dependent variable) x3(condition1, condition2, condition3) ?